# how to catch the value of dialpads pressed button?

Tags: android, call, sip

I am developing a SIP application for making and receiving a call. For that purpose I did analysis on open source project [SipDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/). in that project how they catch the value of `dialpads` pressed button which is sent to the particular method for making a SIP call.

I tried to find the code for that task but I didn't get anything.in which file the code is resides to catch that value in [SipDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls in SipDroid are handled by the SipdroidEngine:

```
org.sipdroid.sipua.SipdroidEngine
```

The method that handles the initial operation is with signature `public boolean call(String target_url,boolean force)` - it transfers the call to the SipDroid UserAgent class and so on, until it reaches the network transport layer. Just check the references of this call method in the whole project and see where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

The dialpad values are called DTMF (Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling).

Most of SipDroid's DTMF stuff is in [dtmf.h](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/jni/spandsp/spandsp/dtmf.h).

You can [search through the source code](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/search?q=dtmf&origq=dtmf&btnG=Search%20Trunk) to see where it is used.

Comment: In SipDroid project.they used default or phones dialpad for making a call.i want to know that how can i do same thing? and where is the code for that? please see this for more information [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161600/how-to-get-the-value-of-dialer-in-android-application)