# Error while using a g729 codec in SipDroid

Tags: android, sip, codec

I am developing a SIP application to make and receive a calls. And i want that application to support g729 codec.

First i have tried with SipDroid an open source project and i have followed the [this steps](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/detail?id=49&q=g729%20codec&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) (followed the comment from 149 to 160) to add g729 codec in [SipDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/).

But g729 codec is not negotiated in my application.i have removed other codecs and added only g729.

In my Asterisk i have added the .so file of g729 codec and in peers account i disallowed all and allowed only g729 but i am getting a error of Incompatible Codec.[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069274/how-to-add-g729-codec-in-android-application/10070748#comment12946883_10070748) for more information about codec configuration and log message of Asterisk CLI.

I am sure there is a problem in Client side because i have added g729 in Asterisk and i am calling on Polycom which has a g729 codec.

Any suggestion and solution about this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks

**Solved:**

please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steps which i have followed

- Downloaded and added the g729_jni.cpp in **jni** folder.[Click here](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/attachmentText?id=49&aid=7963991223373796529&name=g729_jni.cpp&token=025a1iGrmm3wQbx6eSwk0oHoQPw%3A1363787775149)
- Create or Download g729.java file in **org.sipdroid.codecs** package [Click here](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/attachmentText?id=49&aid=-8474206049513172531&name=G729.java&token=95Cri33msKTkLVmXLnlx4hEZiUk%3A1363787775151)
- follow the steps listed here comment no [159](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/detail?id=49&q=g729%20codec&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
- Downloaded the libs.rar file and extract
- add that libs to projects root directory.

  Please refer this if you want to add g729 in SipDroid

  http://junedk.blogspot.com/2013/10/add-g729-codec-in-sipdroid.html

Comment: i need to build g729_jni.so , let me know how to build that , what is the need for libs.rar , since i need to build g729_jni.so

Comment: i am getting errors on #include "g729/typedef.h"
#include "g729/basic_op.h"
#include "g729/ld8a.h"

#include "g729/g729a.h" .. where are these files located ..

Comment: @Kajal libs.rar already contains g729_jni.so for sipdroid project. here the [APK with g729 codec](http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=490197000&name=sipdroid-read-only.apk&token=mandhmm7Evdf9v09X6SyPGHGsZ8%3A1363844152328) which i have uploaded for sipdroid community.

Comment: i am developing a custom implementation with sipdroid , since i need to change the package names , there is an issue with g729 codec because of *kInterfacePath = "org/sipdroid/pjlib/g729"; so in need to rebuild the whole g729.so from source

Comment: @Kajal i have also developed custom implementation of sipdroid and added the support of g729 codec.

Comment: thanks but i need to develop a custom implementation for that i need to know where i can get the whole source to build the codec library , let me know..

Comment: some issues there Description Resource Path Location Type
Type 'JavaVM' could not be resolved   line 54 Semantic Error

Comment: did you successfully created library file for g729 codec ? @Kajal

Comment: let me know where is static 
"JavaVM defined " , its not in typedefs.h

Comment: @Kajal are you compiling through android NDK ?